# Getting Error with .NET REMOTING C#

Tags: .net-remoting

Here is the error I'm getting. I have a simple .Net Remoting setup. This error comes up after a few minutes of the connection being idle.

Object '/7966b546_734e_410d_817a_a0e701f114f6/lfxehvbcznjzkycgbimraglb_1.rem' has been disconnected or does not exist at the server.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You may have a timeout. You can use the native interfaces to set timeout or you can override [virtual object InitializeLifetimeService()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.marshalbyrefobject.initializelifetimeservice.aspx)

If it's not a timeout issue, it may be that you had an error on the server-side. Try attaching your debugger to your server component and play with breakpoints and stepping, esp. in the constructor.

Comment: Thanks. Had to override the function to return null.